# Cross domain localStorage

Tags: html, local-storage

I tried to implement cross domain local storage by copying the code from the below link,

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/

But it is returning 'null'.

I did the following

1. From the page in A.com - stored the value for local storage
2. In the application running in localhost created server.htm as per the code provided in the link
3. created cross_domain_storage.js also as per the link
4. created index.html in localhost application and tried to access the key written at Step 1

But the value returned is 'null'

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cross domain localstorage with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that specific solution but I did write a library that implement cross domain local storage using a shared iframe.

you are welcome to check it out on [github](https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage). It comes with angularjs support as well :)

Comment: Hey! Is there some solution for iPhone?