# localStorage.getItem not working in a different tab

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a simple form with a text input field, for example asking for a Name. The javascript on the page is:

```
var fullName = document.getElementById('fullName').value
```

and then add to the localStorage using:

```
localStorage.setItem('fullName', fullName);
```

when I run this in my browser and type `localStorage` on the same tab, i get my input returned, however if i run `localStorage` on a different tab, the stored data is not showing up. Am I doing something wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Is the other tab opened to a page on the same domain?

Comment: Both tab must be in the same domain

Comment: @JamesThorpe ah I believe that is the problem, is there a way i can select which domains have access to the storage?

Comment: No - [as per the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-localstorage), _"User agents must have a set of local storage areas, one for each origin."_  However, if you're able to change/write code on both domains, [there are alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript).

Comment: @Harvey No way. Just pages from same domain have access to same items.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I understand localstorage is not what im looking to use. Can anyone else suggest a way i can pass data from one tab to another?

Comment: you can always use cookies