# Change Chrome Tab with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to change tabs (got to the next open tab, which is essentially like holding CTRL and pressing the TAB key) through code on a webpage. I want to be able to click anywhere on the page and it will go to the next tab? I understand the clicking on the webpage part, just not how to access the chrome tabs.

Is this even possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you making an extension??

Comment: Its only possible with extensions or if you are opening the tab from your site.. you can't access other tabs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes and no.

If you mean can you advance to the next tab using JavaScript within a website: If you did not open the other tabs via `window.open` (e.g. trying to advance to another tab that was not opened directly from the current website), then no, it is not possible. If it were possible it would be a security risk and give attackers another vector to "ID" a user or potentially find a way to gain access to information about the other tabs a user has open.

If you did open the tabs within the website, you can [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) to them:

```javascript
var newTabs = [];

newTabs.push( window.open("https://example.com", "_blank") );

// Add more tabs?

// Sorry, no way to figure out what the "next" tab is in the
// browser's list of tabs via straight on-site JavaScript,
// just go by next index in the array...
newTabs[0].focus();
```

---

If you are referring to Chrome browser extension that you are working on then, yes, you can advance to the next tab using the [Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). NOTE: This may not work, I did not test it but seems to fit with the documentation and examples I have seen. If you try and find a better solution let me know and I will update):

```
// Query current active tab in the current active window:
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabsArray) {
    // If there are fewer than 2 tabs, you are on the only tab available.
    // Nothing left to do.
    if( tabsArray.length < 2 ) return;
    // Else query tab with incremented index (e.g. next tab):
    chrome.tabs.query({index: (tabsArray[0].index+1)}, function(nextTabsArray){
        // There is no next tab (only 1 tab or user is on last tab)
        if( nextTabsArray.length < 1 ) return;
        // Else, yay! There is a next tab, lets go!
        chrome.tabs.update(nextTabsArray[0].id, {active: true})
    });  
});
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. I planned to try and proceed to another tab (previously opened WITHOUT window.open) through javascript. I think I am going to work on an extension as this will be much more flexible and easier to tackle. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

As @jim said, it is not possible to switch tabs from within a website using JavaScript. But it can be done using the [Chrome Extension Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) which is used in Chrome Extensions.

Below is a code snippet from the extension that I'm working on. It would switch to the very next tab when triggered:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, (tabsArray) => {
  // If only 1 tab is present, do nothing.
  if (tabsArray.length === 1) return;

  // Otherwise switch to the next available tab.
  // Find index of the currently active tab.
  let activeTabIndex = null;
  tabsArray.forEach((tab, index) => {
    if (tab.active === true) {
      activeTabIndex = index;
    }
  });

  // Obtain the next tab. If the current active
  // tab is the last tab, the next tab should be
  // the first tab.
  const nextTab = tabsArray[(activeTabIndex + 1) % tabsArray.length];

  // Switch to the next tab.
  chrome.tabs.update(nextTab.id, { active: true });
});
```

I hope this solves your query. Let me know if you have any better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the window name (typically if you created the window), and you are **on the same domain**, you can switch to it with the window name part of the call to `window.open`.

```js
const myTab = window.open('https://stackexchange.com/questions', 'questions') // first call opens it

myTab.name = 'tags' // renaming window is fine

window.open('https://stackexchange.com/tags', 'tags') // second call switches to it
```

The window **will** reload, so bear that in mind.

If you have access to the tab you wish to switch to, ***theoretically*** you could do the following, using [postMessages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957989/1075247):

```js
// assuming you have this set up:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript

// in the tab for https://same.domain/page-one
Window.name = 'new name'; // set current window name
sendMessage('new name') // using the linked code

// switch to the other tab, e.g. https://same.domain/page-two

// In your message event listener
function receiveMessage(e){
  window.SiblingName = e.data;
}

window.open('https://same.domain/page-one', window.SiblingName)
```

I haven't got the above to work though.