# How can I do to make one tab of Google Chrome focused?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

The main content of the question: Whether Google Chrome's tab can `active` itself, and make it focused when the tab get some message by web socket or not.

The following operation assumes that all are performed in Google Chrome:

1. Open the first tab, called TAB_A. It would connected with server by web socket in lifecycle (the server called TAB_A_SERVER );
2. Open the second tab and a button in this page, called TAB_B. It will send some message to TAB_A_SERVER, and TAB_A_SERVER notify the message to TAB_A when I click the button;
3. TAB_A make itself get focused when got message.

I don't know how to achieve the 3'rd step. Can any big boss help me? Look forward to the solutions...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285381/change-chrome-tab-with-javascript

Comment: @BrettGregson Thanks, I'm going to find other solutions...