# How to programmatically make a tab become the active tab?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge, broadcast-channel

I am using `BroadcastChannel` to remotely control the contents shown in another browser window (on the same PC) displayed on a projector. (Basically, the projected window is an extended desktop display.) It has worked nicely so far on both Chrome and Edge, with a short JS script each in the remote controlling page and the controlled page.

However, the projected browser contents are in three different tabs. Currently, I have to switch focus to that projected window and deftly use Ctrl-Tab to get the tab I want to control to become the active tab.

How do I programmatically select which tab to become active? If there's no generic method, I am happy to have a solution just for Chrome or Edge.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still finding some bandwidth to test it out. Hopefully it will work and I can mark it as answer.

Comment: You can come back any time if you have any updates.

Answer (score 0):

If the tabs are opened with `window.open`, you can switch between them using [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus). The sample code is like below:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window1.focus()" value="switch to window1" />
<input type="button" onclick="window2.focus()" value="switch to window2" />
<script>
    var window1 = window.open("https://samplesite.com/window1");
    var window2 = window.open("https://samplesite.com/window2");
</script>
```

If not, it's impossible to switch between the tabs due to security reasons.  If it were possible, it would be a risk that attackers would find a way to gain access to information about the other tabs a user has opened.

Besides, if you're making a browser extension, you can switch between tabs using [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/). For more information and sample code, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285381/change-chrome-tab-with-javascript/46286558#46286558).