# How can I share JS variables between pages?

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables

So basically I have 2 html pages. 1 has a button and displays the numbers the button generates, the other page (2) only displays. Then I have a script.js file so both files can get the values there. The thing is that when I include page 2 on 1,  it gets the values, but when separated from page 1, it doesn't get any values even with the same script.

So basically it's something like this

**Page 1**

> id="nom" style="font-size: 100px; margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; 
>       font-family:Arial; background: #FFFFF">1

This one gets value from the button with the id (nom) and adds 1 to the number already there.

**Page 2**

Page two has the same code, but is not getting the values when i change them in page 1 with the buttons.

**Script.js**

```
document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML) + 1;
```

The output is done like this.
p id="nom">1

So, this is basically it, i can't get the values on page 2 when I change them in page 1. Any help?

Comment: add them to [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) on page one?

Comment: Not tagging this question as `Java`. There is no evidence taht this question requires java knowledge

Comment: Tree ways : localstorage , websocket or pass arg in url ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Store your variable value in localstorage like this:

**Page 1**

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "yourvalue");
```

**page 2**

```
document.getElementById("yourVariable").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

In your case, It will be:

**Page 1**

```
<html>
<head>Page 1</head>
<body>
<p id="nom">1</p>
<button onclick="YourFunctionName()">Your Button</button>

<script>
function YourFunctionName(){
    document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML) + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("key", parseInt(document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
<p id="nome"></p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("key");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This example only works if the pages are on the same domain. It's also possible to [share variables across domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript), using `window.postMessage()` with an embedded iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Try using localstorage for the same :

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Or for Objects , you can use

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage from Page 1
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage from Page 2
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

> With web storage, web applications can store data locally within the
>   user's browser.
>
> Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included
>   in every server request. Web storage is more secure, and large amounts
>   of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage will do task for you,

> The localStorage allow to save key/value
>   pairs in a web browser.
>
> The localStorage object stores data with no expiration date. The data
>   will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available
>   the next day, week, or year.

**Set value on Page 1**

```
localStorage.setItem("nom", parseInt(document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML) );
```

**Get Value on Page 2**

```
document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("nom")+1;
```