# use localstorage cross domain javascript

Tags: javascript

how to make this localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem work cross-domain

```
if (location.href=="https://cs.money"){
localStorage.setItem('items', document.querySelector("#offer_container_bot > div.items > div > div.p").innerText);
var fasi = localStorage.getItem('items')
};


if (location.href=="https://tynachofinder.ge/finder/"){
document.querySelector("body > header > a").innerHTML = (
   localStorage.getItem('items');
)};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cross domain localstorage with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript)

Comment: this seems like a major security risk for browser allowing that...but i thought that was blocked

Comment: the security model of browsers explicitly rules out doing this. If you need to store data cross-domain (without using frames), the only way you'll be able to do it is to store it in a server-side database and use session and users.

Answer (score 0):

You can't per se. `localStorage` is very much designed to be same-origin only.

You'd need to implement some other form of cross-origin communication such as `tynachofinder.ge` including an `<iframe>` which loads a page from `cs.money` and then the page in the `<iframe>` doing something like:

```
const items = localStorage.getItem('items');
top.postMessage(items, 'https://tynachofinder.ge');
```

with a matching

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event.origin === "https://cs.money")
        console.log(event.data);
    }
}
```

on tynachofinder.ge

Comment: i am making extension so that is the problem i want to get content from cs.money and use it in tynachofinder.ge