# How to share access_token and other data from domain to subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

let's assume we have a domain named accounts.example.com. when a user tries to login after authentication is successful he gets access_token and session_token  etc.  we append this data in url of another subdomain like ABC.example.com. there we save these details in local storage and can make api calls and other stuf.
my point is  can make it possible transferring data from one subdomain to another without appending data in sub domain

Comment: Local storage is locked down intentionally, so you are unfortunately limited. One option is https://stackoverflow.com/a/33957989/231316

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.