# how can i use localstorage.setItem in one application and how can i get localstorage.getItem in another application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use local storage? setItem in one application, and how can I get local storage? getItem in another application

### 1.Application

let data="This is Session"
localstorage.setItem("myurl",data)

### 2.Application

const newdata = localstorage.getItem("myurl")

I am expecting This is session, but it's getting null. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cross domain localstorage with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

**localStorage** is subject to the same-origin policy, which means that data stored in localStorage is accessible only to web pages from the same domain and protocol (e.g., http://example.com). Different applications typically have different domains or protocols, which would prevent them from sharing data in **localStorage**.

You cannot access items from **localstorage** of other domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because, I think, the localstorage is restricted by the hostname, protocol and port.

But maybe you can try this hack : webmessaging :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

> The localStorage read-only property of the window interface allows you
> to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data
> is saved across browser sessions.

Therefore, no, you cannot, unless you use the same domain and port. However, what you could do is use cookies, as they were designed for cross-application usage.